# Finding duplicate values in a multidimensional array for Search Method

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My Code was :

```
$data = array();
foreach ($table as $key => $var) {
    $data[] = ['id' => $var->id, 'value' => $var->designation];
}
```

My Data array should be like this

```
array (
    0 => array (
        'id' => 27,
        'value' => 'laravel',
    ),
    1 => array (
        'id' => 1,
        'value' => 'laravel tester',
    ),
    2 => array (
        'id' => 22,
        'value' => 'laravel developer',
    ),
    3 => array (
        'id' => 23,
        'value' => 'laravel casts',
    ),
    4 => array (
        'id' => 24,
        'value' => 'laravel developer',
    ),
)
```

I need only one value i tried all the php core library function output:

```
array (
    0 => 
  array (
        'id' => 27,
        'value' => 'laravel',
    ),
    1 => array (
        'id' => 1,
        'value' => 'laravel tester',
    ),
    2 => array (
        'id' => 23,
        'value' => 'laravel casts',
    ),
    3 => array (
        'id' => 24,
        'value' => 'laravel developer',
    ),
)
```

Based on the name only i need to remove duplicate bacause in my search bar it shows repeated mode.

Comment: what code you have tried till now

Comment: $input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $data)));

Comment: SORT_REGULAR fuction also i tried

Comment: Please post your code and the output of your code. And also include the expected result.

Comment: exact problem was id's were different based on the name search only i got array like this.

Comment: $table = UserExperience::Where('designation', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->orderBy('designation', 'ASC')->take(10)->get();
        $data=array();
        foreach ($table as $key => $var) {
            $data[]=['id'=>$var->id , 'value'=>$var->designation];
        }

Comment: @SivarajuMani please edit and update the question rather than posting the code as comments

Comment: another thing is sometimes my array comes like this :

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 27,
    'value' => 'laravel',
  ),1 =>  array ('id' => 1, 'value' => 'laravel developer',
  ),2 => array ('id' => 22,'value' => 'laravel developer',
  ),3 => array ('id' => 23,'value' => 'laracast developer',),
  4 => array ('id' => 24,'value' => 'laravel tester',),
)  output i want : 
output :
array ( 0 => array ('value' => 'laravel',),2 => array ('value' => 'laravel developer',),3 => array ('value' => 'laracast developer',),4 => array (
    'value' => 'laravel tester',),)

Comment: @SivarajuMani See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_unique, wich saves indexes,  and get the result by array_intersect_key

```
$temp = array_unique(array_column($arr, 'value'));
$res = array_intersect_key($arr, $temp);
print_r($res);
```